# I keep getting the error 'Unclosed client session' in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio

I am trying to make a discord bot where I can run a specific function, but I keep getting the error 'unclosed client session'

I want to be able to run the 'getMessage' function periodically but for some reason it works on the first call, but on the second it gives me an error. I have tried to mess around with the asyncio but everything I change results in the same or different errors.

Here is my code:

main.py:

```
import time
import instatools
import posterbot

tags = ''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(2):
        posterbot.getMessage()
        time.sleep(10)


def handleMessage(message):
    pass
```

posterbot.py:

```
import discord
import asyncio
import main

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True  # Enable message content for intents

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {client.user.name}')
    await get_first_message()
    await client.close()

async def get_first_message():
    guild_id = 1177834521274626118  # Replace with your guild ID
    channel_id = 1177834521274626121  # Replace with your channel ID

    guild = client.get_guild(guild_id)
    channel = guild.get_channel(channel_id)

    async for message in channel.history(limit=1, oldest_first=True):
        main.handleMessage(message.content)
        print(f'Earliest message: {message.content}')
        break  # Exit the loop after retrieving the first message

# Run the bot
def getMessage():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(client.start(apikey))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you use `client.run` instead of `client.start`, since `client.run` automatically handles loop management:

```py
# Run the bot
def get_message():
    client.run(apikey)
```

If for some reason you need to use `client.start`, I recommend that you use `asyncio.run` to run the method in an asynchronous context:

```py
# Run the bot
async def get_message():
    async with client:
        await client.start(api_key)
```

And in your `main.py` file use `asyncio.run` to run the `get_message` coroutine:

```py
import time
import instatools
import posterbot
import asyncio

tags = ''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(2):
        asyncio.run(posterbot.get_message())
        time.sleep(10)
```